# graphql - Combining results from multiple resolvers into one

Tags: merge, graphql, aggregation, graphql-java

I have a set of functions at the server side which each return a list of objects of the same type based on the passed parameters to the resolvers in the GraphQL query-

```
query {
 objListQuery {
   objResolver1(params) {
    obj-id
   }
   objResolver2(different params) {
    obj-id
   }
   ...
 }
}
```

Here, objResolver1 and objResolver2 send back a list of obj objects.

Server side -

```
function objResolver1(params) -> returns list of obj
function objResolver2(different params) -> returns list of obj
...
```

I want to perform a logical AND between the results of the resolvers that is, find out the common objects in the results of the different resolvers.

Instead of getting the individual lists, I only want the combined list.

One way is to aggregate the results at the client side but this will increase the amount of duplicated data sent by the server.

What is the best way to achieve this at the server side? What changes are required in the schema?

--------------------EDIT--------------------

The data source is a JSON array of obj objects which is obtained from an external service at the server. Data source is **not a database**.

Parameters in each resolver can be one or many. It is used for filtering the objects. For example, the data store will have the structure as:

```
[
{"dateCreated":"2011-08-12T20:17:46.384Z",
 "type":"customer",
 ....
},
{"dateCreated":"2011-08-14T20:17:46.384Z",
 "type":"test",
 ....
}
]
```

resolvers will be of the form:

dateResolver(String startDate, String endDate) -> returns list of obj whose dateCreated is within the range
typeResolver(String[] type) -> returns list of obj whose type is anyone of the values passed in the array.

Comment: aggregate scheme into on single schema and call each of the revolvers inside this aggregated schema

Comment: There are multiple ways to do this, the one most appropriate for you would be based on the exact nature of the data being fetched. Can you be more specific about the schema, like what are the two different resolvers doing? And how are the params different?

Comment: @hazardous Added an example use case.

Answer (score 0):

Assumed you're using a database you're somehow asking how to shift constraints from database- or repository-layer on controller-level.
While this has some weakness on model-level perhaps, it might depend on the class-implementation if you can easily change the `objResolver` in the kind that you just build one that allows more parameters like this:

```
query {
  objListQuery {
    objResolver(params1, params2, constraint) {
      ...
    }
  }
}
```

Like this you could create a database-query that is directly fetching the right result or you can perform several queries and resolve them inside the `objResolver`. If the `constraint` is always `AND` you could leave the parameter away, but perhaps you like to offer the possibility to use also `OR`, `XOR`, or others.

If the amount of parameter-sets is always 2, then it's simple like my code above, also considering the optional constraint. If the amount of parameter-sets might be variable, i.e. 4 or 5, then it's getting complicated if you still want to offer the constraint-parameter(s). Without constraint-parameter(s) it's simple, you just could note the function without parameters but check for the amount of parameters in the caller and handle them accordingly, in the caller you just use so many parameters as required.

```
query {
  objListQuery {
    objResolver() {
      paramArray = getArguments();
    }
  }
}
```

Like written above it's getting hard, if you still want to offer constraint-parameters here, but I'd suggest that would be material for another question.

Comment: Multiple parameters can belong to a single resolver. It will cause the list of parameters in the combined resolver to be very large and the order of the parameters will be difficult to maintain. Also, what if one of the resolvers is not to be utilized for a particular case? Then, null values will have to be passed in the combined resolver.

Comment: Also, the data source is a JSON array, not a database.

Comment: Even if all your use-cases might be known it will take some time to get everything smooth, but perhaps you can explain what you mean with "if one of the resolvers is not to be utilized for a particular case" and if you always use 1 or 2 parameters or more, if you want to offer constraints, etc. Without detailed knowledge of your needs it's hard to answer detailed.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement a [Connection](http://facebook.github.io/relay/graphql/connections.htm) interface, with a single resolver to allow a one-step querying mechanism. You can reduce query endpoints using this technique.

E.g, an example query would look like:

```
allObjects(start: "01-01-2019", end: "04-29-2019", types:["test", "sales"]){
   nodes {
     id,
     dateCreated,
     type
   }
}
```

In the resolver, you can use this criteria to prepare and return the data.

Benefits:

- Less query endpoints.
- Filtering and pagination.

  Your filter interface can be quite fancy:

```
allObjects(
  dateCreated: {
    between:{
      start, 
      end
    }, 
    skipWeekends: true
  }, 
  types: {
    include:[], 
    exclude: []
  }
)
```

- Add new criteria as your needs grow. Start with what you want and take it from there.